# How to satisfy multiple "overlapping" divisibility constraints?

Tags: number-theory

Suppose I have a number of choices I can make ${\{a,b,c,...\}}$, and these choices are grouped together in clauses that must be satisfied. It occurred to me that I can represent this as divisibility constraints by letting the solution be a binary number where each bit is one of the choices ($a \sim 2^0$, $b \sim 2^1$, $c \sim 2^2$, etc). A specific example:

I have clauses $S_1(a,b,c)$, $S_2(a,d,e)$, and $S_3(b,d,f)$ such that a solution  $n$ (which may or may not exist) meets the following criteria:

$n \mod 8 \in [1,2,3,4,5,6]$
$n \mod 32 \in [1,3,5,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,26,28,30]$
$n \mod 64 \in [2,3,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,18,19,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,44,45,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,60,61]$

The problem is to find any $n$, if one exists. I don't need to know all solutions.

The numbers come from the choices. $S_1$ depends on $a,b,c$, and there are the six valid choices. There are also six choices for $S_2(a,d,e)$ but I have to add in "don't care for $S_2$" values for bits $b,c$ for the remainder to come out correctly. Likewise, there are only six valid choices for $S_3(b,d,f)$, but I have to add in "don't care" bits to get the remainder to come out correctly, which blows up the number of possible remainders for $S_3$.

I thought perhaps the Chinese Remainder Theorem would help, but it looks like the divisors must be coprime. I realize perhaps an [SAT Solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) might be a better tool for this problem, but for now I'm wondering if there is anything in number theory that would help me arrive at a solution.

My current solution would be to iterate over all possible choices (64 in this example) and then check each clause (perform the modulus division for each). This will eventually come to a solution (if one exists), but I'm asking if there is a more efficient algorithm to solve these kinds of problems (imagine a problem with $k$ choices where listing all $2^k$ possibilities is infeasible).

For the record, valid $n$ in the example above are: ${ 3, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 18, 19, 22, 26, 28, 30, 33, 35, 37, 41, 44, 45, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 60 }$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SAT problem is famously NP-complete, as mentioned near the beginning of the Wikipedia article you linked to. Any general method for solving a system with clauses like you mention will also be NP-complete, because you could use it to solve SAT.

That means you will not find any easy "shortcuts" around the problem; if you find a way to avoid the kind of exponential blow-up that you observed in $S_3,$ 
you can use that method to solve SAT as well.
If the method only has polynomial complexity you'll then have proved that 
$\mathrm P = \mathrm {NP},$
answering a question that a lot of very smart people have been trying to resolve for many years.

In the meantime, since it's unlikely that you would answer the 
$\mathrm P \stackrel?= \mathrm {NP}$ question any time soon,
you should probably just use an SAT solver if you can get your hands on one.

Alternatively, it's possible there are some special constraints on the kinds of clauses you'll want to deal with that makes your particular problem more tractable than the general SAT problem. But you would have to know something about what those constraints are in order to take advantage of them.